# Using conditions in AntD List Actions

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to use conditions for the actions array in the AntD List Component. The following action should only be added, if the user is an admin and the count is >0. But it seems, that I cannot provide conditions like this inside the actions.

```
 <List dataSource={items} 
                  itemLayout="horizontal"
                  renderItem={item => (
                      <List.Item
                        actions={[
                            {isAdmin && item.count > 0 && <Button onClick={this.moveItemUp(item.key)}>up</Button>,}
                            <a key="list-loadmore-more">more</a>]}
                      >
                        ...
                      </List.Item>
                  )}
```

Any ideas how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React automatically ignores any `null` or `false` values in `render`, so you are safe to leave the values as it exists:

```
 <List dataSource={items} 
  itemLayout="horizontal"
  renderItem={item => (
      <List.Item
        actions={[
            isAdmin && item.count > 0 && <Button onClick={this.moveItemUp(item.key)}>up</Button>,
            <a key="list-loadmore-more">more</a>]}
      >
        ...
      </List.Item>
  )}
></List>
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r2z6ag?file=index.js)

EDIT: If you want to avoid passing the item altogether, you can use the spread operator to do so:

```
actions={[
  <a key="list-loadmore-edit">edit</a>,
  ...(condition ? [<a>Another</a>] : []), 
]}
```

Comment: Thank you, basically it works, but if one item is not displayed, the alignment is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the isAdmin and item.count > 0 condition outside of return and pass dynamically created array to like shown below

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {

      let actionList = [<a key="list-loadmore-more">more</a>];
      if(isAdmin && items.length > 0) actionList.push(<Button onClick={this.moveItemUp(item.key)}>up</Button>)

    return (
      # your code
      <List dataSource={items} 
              itemLayout="horizontal"
              renderItem={item => (
                  <List.Item
                    actions={actionList}
                  >
                    ...
                  </List.Item>
              )}
      # your code
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I think in this example, I am not able to access the item in the code before the return block. (item.count > 0)